# How may I refer to values of variable name with paste() function

Tags: r, paste

```
varlist<-c("aado2","age","albumin")
aado2cut<-c(20,180,360,460)
agecut<-c(35,55,70,80)
albumincut<-c(1.2,1.8,2.2,2.8,4.4)
for (var in varlist){
 print(paste(var,"cut",sep=""))
 }
 #[1] "aado2cut"
 #[1] "agecut"
 #[1] "albumincut"
```

however, in the for loop I want to refer to values of variable name, and the output should be something like:

[1] 20 180 360 460

[1] 35 55 70 80

[1] 1.2 1.8 2.2 2.8 4.4

HoW should I modify my code?

Comment: You can use `get`. `for (var in varlist) print(get(paste(var,"cut",sep="")))`

Comment: You might want to look at [alternatives to for loops](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-on-loops-in-r#gs.787DsTo). In addition putting your data in a data frame might be helpful for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `mget` and `ls`.

```
mget(ls(pattern="cut"))

# $aado2cut
# [1]  20 180 360 460
# 
# $agecut
# [1] 35 55 70 80
# 
# $albumincut
# [1] 1.2 1.8 2.2 2.8 4.4
```

The result is a list containing all your variables verifying a certain pattern.